# IA-32 | reordering issue in a multiprocessor environment

Tags: serialization, assembly, x86

I want to perform an atomic 'and' operation on IA-32.

Please consider the following situation:

```
; processor 0
lea     edx, var
mov  ecx, mask
mov  eax, [edx]
lock and [edx], ecx

; processor 1
lea     edx, var
mov  eax, 0xff
xchg [edx], eax
```

I'm not sure if it's possible that the store to 'var' by processor 1 can or cannot occure between the load and the store to 'var' by processor 0.
So, is this working or do I need to spin lock like this:

```
; processor 0
push ebx
lea  edx, var
mov  ecx, mask
@@loop:
mov  ebx, [edx]
mov  eax, ebx
and  eax, ecx
lock cmpxchg [edx], eax
cmp  eax, ebx
jne  @@loop
pop  ebx
```

Thanks for any answer. Best regards.

EDIT:
In other words:
I want to perform the conjunction in 'Processor 0' and need to fetch the initial value.

Answer (score 0):

An xchg that references memory automatically locks the bus (or locks the cache when/if the data is already in the cache). See the [Intel reference manual](http://www.intel.com/Assets/PDF/manual/253668.pdf), §8.3.1. (Warning: I haven't looked hard recently, but Intel used to rearrange their web site, invalidating links fairly quickly. If so, Googling for something like "intel reference 3a" should turn it up).

Comment: I've read the System Programing Guide 3A: Section 8.3 over and over again, but especially the situation above isn't totally clear to me. And as a side note - this isn't about atomicity at all, it's about instruction ordering.

Comment: @FrEEzE2046: Sorry -- I read things backwards, and thought you were asking whether the other store could happen between the load and store implicit in the `xchg`. Are you talking about the L/S implicit in the `and [edx],ecx`?

Comment: Let's assume the initial value of var = '31' and mask = '15'. 'Processor 0' is loading from var's address (mov  eax, [edx]). Right after that, he's performing a read-modify-write conjunction (lock and [edx], ecx). But, at potentially same time, 'Processor 1' is also performing a write operation to that memory location (mov  eax, 0xff, xchg [edx], eax). Now I'm not sure, if it's guaranteed that the value I'm storing in 'Procesor 0' to the eax - register is the same I'm performing the conjunction on. I need to be sure, because I'm ussing this value as result and it should be the expected.